The Haflaah and "our spiritual eyes"
Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita quotes from the Haflaah, and seemingly the Chasam Sofer (who was a student of the Haflaah) also quotes it, and explains that:

we have physical eyes and spiritual eyes. They are opposites. The more we close our physical eyes, the more our spiritual eyes are open wide.

Does anyone know where the Haflaah says this (bonus points for bringing both the original Haflaah, and the Chasam Sofer).

חתם סופר - דרשות - חלק ב  - דף שז

אין תח"י בכי"ק של מרן מ”ש על פסוק זה, אבל בפנקס הרב ר' פישל סופר ז”ל
הבי' מרבו הח”ס מה אמר בשם הפלאה והוא רעיון הנ"ל, וז"ל: ותפקחנה עיני
שניהם וידעו כי ערומים הם. כו עיני הבשר של אדם הם המחשיכין את האדם
להשיג אור העליון. וביותר שאדם סוגר עיני בשר, יותר מאיר עיני רוחני של
אדם, להשיג סודות עליונות. וזהו כחשיכה כאורה שכל מה שיש חשך בעיני הבשר
של אדם, תוסיף אורה ע"י עיני רוחני שלו, גם זה המכוון בפסוק בי עין בעין
יראו בשוב הי. היינו העיני רוחני המאירים בתוך עיני הבשר. ומתחלה קודם
החטא היו עיני בשר שלהם כמעט סגורים, והעיני רוחני' מאירים להם, ולא היה
להם יצה”ר ואין כאן בושה וערות דבר. והראי’ שמתחלה דבר ה' עמהם ועכשיו
אסור לקרוא שום דבר קדושה בגילוי אבר. וזו ותפקחנה עיני שניהם' היינו
עיני הבשר הגשמיות וידעו כי ערומים הם שנכנס בהם היצה”ר ונעשה אותו מקום
ערוה לכן ויתחבא האדם. עכ”ל. ועי’ לעיל בדרוש האחרון לח' טבת ד”ה ולבוא
אל וכו’ בשם הפלאה מזה וכן בדרוש לז’ אדר תקצ”ז לפ"ק ד"ה אחז”ל ‏ מהנ”ל
ע”ש, ועי' בפנים יפות בפ'. בראשית בפסוק ויהיו שניהם וגו’ ובפסוק ויתחבא
וגו’ נרפס. סהנ”ל.

This is repeated nearly verbatim in תורת משה (מהדורא תנינא) חלק א דף ה עמ א

ותפקחנה עיני שניהם וידעו כי ערומים הם: אמר מורי ההפלאה זצ"ל כי עיני
הבשר של אדם הם המחשיכין את האדם להשיג אור עליון וביותר שאדם סוגר עיני
הבשר  יותר מאיר עיני רוחני של אדם להשיג סודות עליונים. וזהו כחשיכה
כאורה. שכל מה שחשך בעיני של בשר של אדם  תוסיף אורה  ע"י עיני רוחני שלו
. וגם זה במובן הקרא כי עין בעין יראו בשוב ה' היינו עיני רוחני המאירים
בתוך  עיני הבשר. ומתחילה קודם החטא היו עיני בשר שלהם כמעט סגורים ועיני
רוחני היו  מאירים להם ולא היו להם יצה"ר. ואין כאן בושה  וערות דבר
והראי' שמתחילה דבר  ה' עמהם . ועכשיו אסור לקרוא שום דבר קדושה בגילוי
אבר וז"ש ותפקחנה עיני שניהם  היינו הבשר הגשמי וידעו כי ערומים הם שנכנס
בהם יצה"ר ותהוה אותו מקום ערוה לכך ויתחבא האדם.
“And the eyes of them both were opened, and they knew that they were
naked”: My teacher the Haflaah zs”l said that the eyes of man obscure
from man the ability to understand the Divine-light and further that
when man closes his eyes of flesh his spiritual eyes are illumined and
he more readily understands Divine-secrets. Such that darkness is as
light. For anything that darkens the human eyes of flesh thereby
increases light by means of his spiritual eyes. And this is what is
intended by the scriptural passage "for they shall see, eye to eye,
God returning to Sion" (Isaiah 52:8), for spiritual eyes illuminate
from within eyes of flesh. And at the outset, prior to the sin [of
eating from the tree] their eyes of flesh were practically closed and
their spiritual eyes were illuminated for them and they didn’t have an
evil inclination. And there was no shame, and nakedness, and at the
outset God spoke with them. And now it is forbidden to read any matter
of sanctity with uncovered organs, and thus it was written “And the
eyes of them both were opened” for the flesh and physicality “and they
knew they were naked” for the evil inclination entered into them and
‘that place’ became nakedness and so “the man hid himself” (Gen. 3:8).

I've only translated the selection from Torath Moshe as the section in the Derashoth is nearly verbatim identical

"וביותר שארם סוגר עיני בשר, יותר מאיר עיני רוחני של אדם, להשיג סודות עליונות" - Thanks very much! For bonus points, do you know where the Haflaah is?

Thanks for the opportunity to find it (and thereby learn about the idea)... if I am understanding correctly, it says that R. Fishel Sofer recorded this in his notebook from his rebbie the Hatham Sofer, who said it in the name of the Haflaah... so I'm not sure that the Haflaah ever actually committed it to writing (otherwise he would have presumably been cited directly).

Ah, that might be it yes. Thanks for helping out.

I found in the sefer Segulos HaSofer, that the Shelah is also connected to this. The posuk in Bereishis 3:7 says the eyes of Adam and Chava were opened, they saw they were naked. Rabbi Fishel Sofer brings from the Shelah that "The more a person closes the eyes of his flesh, the more the spiritual eyes of man illuminate, to attain lofty secrets." - is this true?

I can't get onto Otzar right now, but what is the page number (in case the link doesn't work for me). I'm not sure... but that would make sense, the Haflaah is a descendant of the Shelah if I am not mistaken.

It is on 140, but it does not work anymore here. I found it by looking up the quote I put into the first comment

I checked p. 140 of Seguloth ha-Sofer and didn't see the Shelah mentioned

it is here

And here in Toras Moshe (Bereishis, p. 13) https://i.postimg.cc/1t7kr0Fr/image.png sv. ומתחלה קודם החטא היו עיני בשר שלהם כמעט סגורים

I already edited the post to include the Torath Moshe 16 hrs ago ;) but I'm still not seeing any reference to the Shelah...

Hmm, than that is my fault. It seems to refer to Drashos Chasam Sofer indeed (בדרשות חתם סופר (דף ק"א טו"ד)).

No worries : - )

One last question haha. But could you maybe provide hebrew, non rashi script text and translation to the two pieces?

@Shmuel I posted the Hebrew text of both, and only translated the selection from Torath Moshe... hope you find that sufficiently satisfying :)
